# How to parse string with links into html links

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a string below:

```js
const input = `This is a link: https://www.google.com/, this is another link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.`
```

How would I parse that string and output another string that looks as follows in js:

```js
const output = `This is a link: <a href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a>, this is another link: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask</a>.`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one liner:

```js
const input = `This is a link: https://www.google.com/, this is another link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.`;

let output = input.replace(/(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/g, (x)=>'<a href="'+x+'">'+x+'</a>'); 

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need help of regular expressions.

You can start here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

You can check this: [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

From here you should capture the coincident regular expression and use those matches to replace it on the original input string.

You can go with a classical String replace taking advantage of the Template literals building the replacement using the same replaced text.

Interesting references about this two terms:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

And you can practice in general with this regular expression playground https://regexr.com/

```js
const input = `This is a link: https://www.google.com/, this is another link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.`

const urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))/g;

const matches = input.match(urlRegex);

let output = input;

for(let match of matches){
  output = output.replace(match, `<a href="${match}">${match}</a>`);
}
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a library to already do this?

Comment: I would recommend this framework http://vanilla-js.com/ 

Just joking  

Plain Javascript is quite good and performant doing this.

Comment: Ok got down the regex expression and learned about the replace method, however, how do I replace it with <a> element? ```replace(regex, what goes here?)```

Comment: "what goes here?" => `(x)=>'<a href="'+x+'">'+x+'</a>'`